# How to select distinct rows in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

When I perform:

```
SELECT t.testname , r.testrange 
FROM test as t 
LEFT JOIN range r ON t.test_id = r.test_id  
WHERE  r.test_id = 25;
```

I got results like below :-

```
    +-----------+---------------------+
    | testname  | testrange           |
    +-----------+---------------------+
    | A:G RATIO | 15-20 for children  |
    | A:G RATIO | 30-60 for adults    |
    | A:G RATIO | 100 - 200 for women |
    +-----------+---------------------+
```

As you can see, testname is repeated in first column. So how could I get result like this -

```
    +-----------+---------------------+
    | testname  | testrange           |
    +-----------+---------------------+
    | A:G RATIO | 15-20 for children  |
    |    --     | 30-60 for adults    |
    |    --     | 100 - 200 for women |
    +-----------+---------------------+
```

i.e. only unique testname should be come in testname column along with their all testrange in testrange column.

Comment: Not only that you can't, what would even be the point of it?

Comment: The question is misguided, and the title is quite bad, but I don't agree with these closevotes. As questions go, it's clear and possibly useful.

Comment: The question is pointless. Database handles querying the data, not formatting the outpu. Various application languages deal with displaying it. This is done so easily with array implementation of any language and even attempting to do it on a database level would involve ugly code or practices.

Answer (score 1):

You can use user-defined variables to assign a row number value to each row, so your code will be similar to the following:

```
select 
  case when rn = 1 then testname else '' end testname,
  testrange
from
(
  select t.testname,
    r.testrange,
    @row:=case when @prev=t.testname then @row else 0 end +1 rn,
    @prev:=testname
  FROM test as t 
  LEFT JOIN `range` r ON t.test_id = r.test_id  
  cross join (select @row:=0, @prev:=null) c
  WHERE  r.test_id = 25
  order by t.testname
) src
order by rn
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c2e5/2)

Answer (score 0):

If you need one row you should use group concat after you get the result you can explode column.

```
SELECT
  t.testname,
  GROUP_CONCAT(r.testrange) AS testrange
FROM test as t
  LEFT JOIN range r
    ON t.test_id = r.test_id
WHERE r.test_id = 25
GROUP BY r.testrange;
```

The output you want seem strange. See the demo [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c2e5/11).